# KeyFrame - animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx, keyframe

How can I use variable "t" which is in the math pattern included in one of the contructor argument. The "t" corresponds to time which make chart move to the right.

```
public void update(final Scene scene) {

  final Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot(); 
  final Chart chart = new Chart(x -> Math.exp(-(Math.pow((x-t ), 2)))
                                     * Math.cos((2*Math.PI*(x-t))/l),
                                    -1, 1, 0.01,
                                    new Axes(1000, 1000, -1, 1, 0.1, -1, 1, 0.1)
                      );

  root.getChildren().add(chart);
  Timeline timeLine = new Timeline(Timeline.INDEFINITE, 
                                  new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000),
                                  x -> {}));    
  timeLine.setAutoReverse(true);
  timeLine.play();             
}
```

If I could do this inside the `KeyFrame`, that could resolve my problem. but can not.

```
while(t < 1) {
     t+=0.05;
     chart = new Chart(x -> Math.exp(-(Math.pow((x-t ),2)))*Math.cos((2*Math.PI*(x-t))/l),
                        -1, 1, 0.01, new Axes(1000, 1000,
                                -1, 1, 0.1, -1, 1, 0.1)
                        );
}
```

Comment: That `Chart` class doesn't look familiar. It's certainly not `javafx.scene.chart.Chart`... But if it's well designed it allows assigning the data without recreating the class... But if you need to access the time, you should perhaps use an [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only local variables you can access inside a lambda expression are `final` or effectively final variables. Since `t` is modified (`t+=0.05`), it is neither final nor effectively final.

All you need is to copy its value to a final variable:

```
while(t < 1) {
     t+=0.05;
     final double thisT = t ;
     chart = new Chart(x -> Math.exp(-(Math.pow((x-thisT ),2)))*Math.cos((2*Math.PI*(x-thisT))/l),
                        -1, 1, 0.01, new Axes(1000, 1000,
                                -1, 1, 0.1, -1, 1, 0.1)
                        );
}
```